# Protractor: how to debug unhandled Promise Rejections?

Tags: node.js, protractor

After a huge PR, our E2E has started taking almost 4 hours to execute.

Reading the log, I've found the following line:

> (node:6600) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
> rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
> function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
> not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled
> promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict`
> (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 2)

The official docs did not bring any information, so I've found [this doc](https://nodesource.com/blog/diagnostics-in-NodeJS-1), that says:

> --unhandled-rejections strict mode causes an uncaught exception

The question is:
is there any way to use this flag with Protractor? Or how can I debug to find this exception?

Comment: that's not the cause of the problem. Compare reports before PR and after and see which tests take longer. Or all? I didn't see your code, but I already know you likely to have at least 2 major problems in your project. But lets start 1 by 1

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov with this resource it would log the exception. I've checked the PR and there isn't any new async call. At this moment I don't have any report that shows the duration of each test. I will look for it.

Comment: when you say PR, do you mean changes to the application under test, or updates to test automation?